# Scale div to browser height vh troubles

Tags: html, css

I want the content inside of my div to scale with the browser vertically to prevent the need for scrolling The images will be different orientations so the width will be different. I know this can be achieved horizontally with width:100%; but max-height:100%; or height:auto; both still extend past the browser window for me and I'm not sure why.

**EDIT:** Had a lot of additional modal code in here, and simplified it down to the html/css and switched from simple width:100% height: 100% to vh and vw.

Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/duckyduck/6soe8zs0/

What's happening:
[image]

How I want it to look:
[image]
[image]

```
<body>
<style>

.modal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing:border-box;

  left: 0;
  top: 0;
height: 100%;
width:100%;


  overflow:auto;
  background-color:#D81E21;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;/*modal x button */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #7E7DE1;
  max-height: 50vh;
  max-width:70vw;
  margin: auto;
  }



.mySlides{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}



.roll-img { 
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.column {
flex:1;
}


.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}


</style>



<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="images/5_2.jpg">
        </div>


        <div class="caption-container">
          <p id="caption"></p>
        </div> 


      <div class="roll-img">
        <div class="column">
            <img class="demo cursor" src="images/5_2.jpg">
        </div>
      </div> <!--roll-img-->


  </div> <!--modal-content-->
</div> <!--myModal-->




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your **.modal-content** width is **30%**. it might help

```
.modal-content .mySlides img {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

to fit image in 30% width of model content

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond,lowering the width doesn't work unfortunately because the images will vary in dimension. I added an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

min-height: 100vh;

vh refers to the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the desired result by applying 4 things:

1. `max-width: 90vw;` ensures that the object will never exceed 90% of the screen width.
2. `max-height: 90vh;` ensures that the object will never exceed 90% of the screen height.
3. `width: auto;` adjusts the width to maintain the original aspect ratio
4. `height: auto;` adjusts the width to maintain the original aspect ratio

With these four **combined,** the object will **always** be fully in view and you will not need to scroll the screen.

**Working example:** 
(open in full screen and resize vertically or horizontally to see the effect)

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.adjust {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="adjust" src="https://unsplash.it/3000/3000">
```

Comment: I updated the post with your suggestion and took out all of the additional modal code, unfortunately I got the div to respond to vh and vw but for some reason the contents themselves aren't having it.